# ApacheTop Time Is Incorrect

Tags: apache, ubuntu

[image]

As you can see from the picture, the first console is running `apachetop` and the second one is showing current pc time.Why is the differences?

I run apachetop using ubuntu 14.04 through vagrant.

I think apachetop is using utc time, how to force `apachetop` to use local pc time?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

http://www.christopherirish.com/2012/03/21/how-to-set-the-timezone-on-ubuntu-server/

then later you can automate that.